# Disable wmic - Windows Management Instrumentation

Tags: windows, ransomware

Regarding Petya ransomware, I read that is advisable to disable vmic, afaik aka "Windows Management Instrumentation" in services.msc.

But if I am stopping this, this will also stop "Security Center", which I think is bad.

The question: How to disable wmic do harden the os against Petya?

Comment: If you stop wmic it also stops firewall which is not good.

Comment: then how to disable wmic?

Comment: I find that the virus targets MBR. So if anyone use UEFI with GPT partition, is his/her PC safe?